# UBUNTU wont come up

Tags: boot

My windows vista os will not work.  I installed Ubuntu on a USB drive and put the USB drive at the top of the boot list so I can boot off Ubuntu and install it but Ubuntu will not come up.  Can you install Ubuntu off a USB drive if your windows OS is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install ubuntu from a usb,if your previously installed windows Os was not working.If your Ubuntu Os was not shown on the grub then run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).